# How to implement EF many to many relations in ASP MVC without a MultiSelectBox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a application using Entity Framework 6.1 and ASP.NET MVC5. I got the following model:

```
class Person {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public List<Book> Books {get; set;}
}

class Book {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    [Required]
    public String Title {get; set;}
    public List<Person> Authors {get; set;}
}
```

For editing a single Book I got this view-model:

```
class BookViewModel {
    public String Title {get; set;}
    public List<Int32> AuthorIds {get; set;}
    public List<PersonViewModel> Authors {get; set;}
}

class PersonViewModel {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

And the view:

```
<h1>Book @Model.Title</h1>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Authors)
```

I further got a jQuery dialog where the user can search for and select a `Person` from a really big ammount of Persons. This dialog is shown using a "Add author"-button. When the dialog is closed, I get the `Id` of the `Person` the user did choose. A `XmlHttpRequest` returns the visible markup for a `Person`, so I can add it to the DOM.

Every single Author displayed also has a "Remove"-button.

Now I imagine having a list of hidden fields for getting the selected Authors in my POST-data:

```
AuthorIds[0]=17
AuthorIds[1]=44
AuthorIds[2]=90234
```

When I would get my POST-data in this way, I could auto-bind my model and map it very comfortable. Yet the client side has some open issues:

- My real graph-paths are more complex (like `Thing[3].Subthing[1].Book[0].AuthorIds[2]`). How would I add an entry when there is none (a initially empty collection) where I can copy the path from?
- How would I fill the gap in the index when I remove an item not from the end?

Am I on the wrong track here? Should I have a different approach when dealing with such a association?

Comment: How did the `AuthorIds[0]=17` got rendered ? Could you please show any html code for that ?

Comment: I did "imagine" them. After all a collection of numbers should be passed like this for HTML forms.

Comment: But I dropped that whole approach. I ended up rendering the list of Authors while only passing their Ids. So my path now looks like `Author[0].Id=17`.